# Subquery in FROM clause not working

Tags: mysql, sql

Using MySQL 5.7.14, the following query does not work while with version 5.6.17 it does :

```
SELECT prep.Mbr_Id AS Mbr, 
       prep.Pra_Id AS Pra, 
       SUM( prep.MPra_VAL ) AS Val 
FROM    
    (
      SELECT membres.Mbr_Id AS Mbr_Id, 
             pratiques.Pra_Id AS Pra_Id, 
             0 AS MPra_VAL 
      FROM membres 
      JOIN pratiques 
      WHERE pratiques.Pra_Index = 1 
              UNION ALL 
      SELECT membres_pratiques.MPra_Mbr_Id AS Mbr_Id, 
             membres_pratiques.MPra_Pra_Id AS Pra_Id, 
             membres_pratiques.MPra_Val AS MPra_VAL 
      FROM membres_pratiques 
    ) AS prep
GROUP BY prep.Mbr_Id, 
         prep.Pra_Id
```

Writing this query in phpMyAdmin (5.6.25) in the SQL tab, I have the following errors :

```
. on "(" line, after the first FROM clause : 
    . an expression was expected ( close to ( )
    . unexpected token ( close to ) )
. on SELECT line after the ")" : 
    . this type of clause has already been analysed ( close to ) )
```

Does anyone have an idea of what could be the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Try a simpler form of the query:

```
SELECT m.Mbr_Id, p.Pra_Id, mp.MPra_VAL 
FROM membres m CROSS JOIN
     pratiques p LEFT JOIN
     membres_pratiques mp
     ON mp.MPra_Mbr_Id = m.Mbr_Id AND mp.MPra_Pra_Id = p.Pra_Id
WHERE p.Pra_Index = 1 ;
```

The aggregation is only necessary if you have multiple rows for pairs of "membres" and "pratiques" in `membres_pratiques`.

Comment: The problem is that I have these errors in ALL my queries using FROM ( SELECT ... ) AS table... It looks like there was a parameter, somewhere, wich does not allow to use "(" in that purpose.

Comment: @Pve . . . Well, the *particular* query that you asked about can be radically simplified and work in any database.  I would suggest that you ask *another* question that is more general than this question.

Comment: As I said in my edited comment, it happens in ALL my queries using a subquery in the FROM clause...

Comment: @Pve . . . This question is about *one* specific query.  This answer (presumably) addresses the question, providing a more efficient and more concise query.  If you change the question, you will invalidate this answer, which can draw downvotes. So, changing the question is rude.  The best course of action is to ask *another* question that explains that the problem affects multiple queries.  You might want to include at least two examples of such queries.

Comment: Yes you're right.  I posted a new one with more précisions.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT membres.Mbr_Id AS Mbr_Id, pratiques.Pra_Id AS Pra_Id,membres_pratiques.MPra_Val AS MPra_VAL
FROM membres full outer join membres_pratiques  on 
(membres.Mbr_Id = membres_pratiques.MPra_Mbr_Id) and
(prep.Pra_Id=membres_pratiques.MPra_Pra_Id)